# Get city name from array of strings PHP

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have an array contain some strings each string contain city name.

City name sometime exist at the begin of the string and sometimes in the middle and sometimes in the end of the string.

**The Question**

How do I make a new array that contain only cities name?

```
$messagesStrings = [
    'H…cus',
    'Fire reported in the main market in Mogadishu',
    'Funtimes in Ibiza',
    'Lovely shisa in Cairo,Egypt',
    'Blimey! Protests in Tahrir , can't go home',
    'Stuck in traffic in Nairobi',
    'Kathmandu is beatiful',
    'Lovely football at the Bernabau, Madrid, Spain',
    'I hate my government, Athens',
    'Life is full of surprises in Istanbul'
];
```

Comment: Do you have a list or db of all possible cities?

Comment: You can try and tokenize your strings to filter out nouns and then find out if it's a place by using some service like this [Geography link](https://github.com/ushahidi/geograpy)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$messagesStrings = [
    'H…cus',
    'Fire reported in the main market in Mogadishu',
    'Funtimes in Ibiza',
    'Lovely shisa in Cairo,Egypt',
    'Blimey! Protests in Tahrir , can\'t go home',
    'Stuck in traffic in Nairobi',
    'Kathmandu is beatiful',
    'Lovely football at the Bernabau, Madrid, Spain',
    'I hate my government, Athens',
    'Life is full of surprises in Istanbul'
];

$regex = '/Madrid|Spain|Ibiza/';

preg_match_all($regex, implode(' ', $messagesStrings), $matches);

var_dump($matches[0]);
```

**Output**

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "Ibiza"
  [1]=>
  string(6) "Madrid"
  [2]=>
  string(5) "Spain"
}
```

**Live Example**

[Repl](https://repl.it/repls/RepentantDeeppinkJavabytecode)

Answer (score 0):

Well, due the fact, that there could be everything in the search string, you would need a list of cities in your database, and find those in the search string itself. If there is nothing similar, it would mean, even if it would be a real city, it would not be in the database, and so it would not be getable there. But if you can find a similar one, you can remove it from the search string and get the details for the city from the database.